# How to push xhtml validation via a proxy in telerik rad editor

Tags: asp.net, .net, proxy, telerik, radeditor

I have a rad editor with the "xhtml validation" button enabled.  Our users like this feature apparently.  It appears that the validation check is a server-side request and my web servers need to make all net requests via a proxy.

Is there anyway to override the functionality and make the request manually via a proxy or simply add my proxy settings in and call the base object's validation routine??

I've tried setting proxy settings in IE on the server but to no avail..  Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I have never fiddled into this but I think it may be possible to alter the source code to fulfil your needs and build the assembly yourself. I am not sure if .NET has built-in features related to using proxies, however. Your local network admins may be able to help with a way to set up proxis on an OS level though

Comment: Thanks @rdmptn, I don't have access to the source, I was hoping there was a non-code-modifying method.

Comment: You should have access to the source in your telerik account where you download the controls from. Try talking to the network admins or sys admins for a os-wide solution, as I do not think you can do this proxy thing from code. Last idea - try using the dialogs from user controls in the solution docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/editor/functionality/dialogs/externaldialogspath-property so you can edit its code easier

Comment: Thanks @rdmptn, we've just removed the feature from the UI.  When I said "I don't have access to source", I meant me specifically, there is only one guy in the company who has access and he doesn't want us to spend the time on modifying the code in this way.  Makes upgrades to newer controls difficult, etc.

Comment: The dialogs are in the assembly and you can add them to the solution with a single click via the Smart Tag: http://screencast.com/t/b9K2cpXUoCJ.
As for access to the source - you may want to check that with your legal department, because you are violating the EULA of the controls. Everyone creating code with them must have a license (and thus, will have access to the source). Speak with sales@telerik.com and your license holders to confirm, of course.